# c3.js change color pattern after generating chart

Tags: javascript, charts, c3

In c3.js I can load custom color pattern when generating chart.
Is there any way to change it after I generated chart?
I know there is **color** function but I can't really use it because c3 sends id of the sequence that it wants to know color for, not its order.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue on github here: [c3 github thread](https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/issues/913) which can be usefull for you.

Comment: The problem is - I don't know all ids of sequences since they are added dynamicly. That is why color.pattern is usefull - you give it an array of colors and it applies to to sequences in order.

Answer (score 0):

I had to color y axix lines. I gave each of them a class and them later on change the label color and line color by

```
var chart = c3.generate(...
            onrendered: function(){
                if(lines){
                    for(var i=0; i < lines.length; i++){
                        d3.select("g." + lines[i].class + " line").style({stroke: lines[i].color, fill: lines[i].color});
                        d3.select("g." + lines[i].class + " text").style({stroke: lines[i].color, fill: lines[i].color});
                    }
                }                   
            }
        });
```